# User Form and legend New look

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have the following UI laid out for a simple form. 
http://jsfiddle.net/h5Zbj/2/
The input type="checkbox" is actually a chekboxlist in my asp.net form. Can anyone suggest on adding some style. I found this one on google but it actually has a lot more stuff than I need. I am trying to modify this script to just fit my need of getting the legend, textboxes look appealing. Has anyone done this before?
http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Personal Infor </legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' />
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' />
            </td>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' />
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' />
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Access Rights</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Start" value="Bike"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Admi" value="Admin">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: you want to style your form just like the one you mentioned???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5Zbj/8/

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <fieldset class="section">
      <legend>Personal Info</legend>
      <div class="content">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' />
                </td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>
                    <input type='text' />
                </td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>
                <input type='text' />
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </div>                                
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Styling is applied, as you suggested.

I hope it helps.